# How to use upload() command in Colab with out manual input of file location?

Tags: python, input, import, output, google-colaboratory

How to use upload() command in Colab with out manual input of file location?

The below `upload()`  will ask the user for file location and you have to manually input the file.  But I would like to put the local location in the `upload()` command ... like `upload(C:\documents\file)`.   I have searched StackOverflow but this has not been addressed. Yes, one can upload Google drive etc but is there a direct way to do this without manually putting in the files.

```
# THIS THE CODE FROM COLABS THAT PRODUCES A TEXT INPUT BOX
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()





#MY CODE TRIES TO USE PATH FROM MY LAPTOP

from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload(C:\Users\jennies laptop\Documents\tos program)
```

My code gives an error code.

```
File "<ipython-input-10-983842aba897>", line 3
    uploaded = files.upload(C:\Users\jennies laptop\Documents\tos program)
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error you're getting is for an unquoted string literal; i.e. in Python you cannot say `foo(Bar)` to pass the string `Bar` to the function `foo`, you must use quotes as in `foo("Bar")`.

The functionality you're hoping for does not exist; `files.upload()` does not accept an argument, and it is not possible to implement what you hope for because the HTML spec doesn't allow asking for a particular file that way:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#file-upload-state-(type=file)